# Section Index Titles after Parsing JSON Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create dynamic sectionIndexTitles for my tableView. I want to get all of the character names and then get the first letter of the name to create sectionIndexTitles, but I am having difficulty doing so.

I get the JSON from URL:

```
func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let url = URL(string: "mytestURL")
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
    
    session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            do {
                characters = try JSONDecoder().decode([CharacterStats].self, from: data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completed()
                }
            } catch {
                print("JSON Error")
            }
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
[
 {
  "name": "Batman",
  "type": "DC",
  "gender": "male",
},
{
  "name": "Captain America",
  "type": "Marvel",
  "gender": "male",
},
{
  "name": "Captain Marvel",
  "type": "Marvel",
  "gender": "female",
}
]
```

And my struct looks like this:

```
public struct CharacterStats: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let type: String?
    let gender: String?
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you try "public struct CharacterStats: Codable ?"

Comment: @achu no error per se. I'm not sure how to go about getting just the names to be able to extract the first letter for the indexTitles.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a sample code for this here https://github.com/achuaswani/ListItemExample.git